# Change variable based on Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I need an event, that changes a variable based on which TableViewCell I click. But unlike an action connected to a button, there is no action indicator for table view cells at all. So my question is:

I want to make a TableView that contains items of an array. Based on which item I click, I want to change my variable so that the result on the next ViewController depends on which button you click.

So to make things easier, here is an example what I want the app to look like:

On the first TableViewController I have a list based on an array and on the second ViewController I have a label that shows text based on the variable.

I have a `nameArray = ["Mum", "Brother", "Me"]` and a `weightArray = [140, 160, 120]` and a variable `weight = 0`. The label on the second ViewController tells the var weight. So when you click on "Mum" in the TableView I want the next ViewController to say 140, when I click on "Brother" then 160 and so on...

Until here everything works just fine and I have no problems with anything but changing the var based on what I click.

Long story, short sense:

I want an Action for the TableViewCell that changes the var like in an Action connected to a Button, but there is no Action outlet for Cells at all.

Comment: See [`UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 1):

Use this method. Use indexPath.row to find what row number you selected

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! 
     switch cell.labelSubView.text as! String {
     case "Mum":
         self.weight = weightArray[0]
     case "Brother"
         self.weight = weightArray[1]
     and so on..
     ..
     default:
         statements
     }
 }
```

**Note** A better alternative

I also considered a case where you have too many entries in nameArray and switch statement might not be good. In that case you can get the text inside the selected row by `cell.labelSubView.text as! String`

next you can check if the nameArray contains the cell text and get the index of the name that matches the cell text. Next you can get the required weight at the same index in `weightArray`. And then do `self.weight = weightArray[requiredIndex]`

Hope this helps.

**Update** : My experienced friend @Duncan mentioned down below that switch statement in this case is a bad coding practice . I am not going to delete it because it is a lesson for me and also my fellow programmers who are relatively new to programming. So i have put it in a yellow box, stating that it is **not a good code**

**A better option for this would be**  :

1. As Duncan mentions, creating an array of dictionary is a good option
2. Second option is the option in my answer after my Note

Comment: Your answer is a step in the right direction, but you show the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method creating a **local** variable row and saving the selected row there. That doesn't help the OP because that variable goes away as soon as the function finishes.

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, that's terrible advice.  Why write a custom switch statement that you have to maintain as your data changes. Why not create an array of dictionaries or other data structures that hold the data and then just past the data.

Comment: Okay, I thought that and I completely agree with you. i gave him this advice because that can get his work quickly and easily without getting into "array of dictionaries."
However, I added a Note in my answer that is a better alternative

Comment: This is a case of "if you can't afford the time to do it right, when can you afford the time to do it over?" Hard-coding model data into a switch statement in your view controller is a truly bad idea, for a multitude of reasons. You should just delete that part of your answer. It's objectively very bad advice.

Comment: @DuncanC, I have updated the answer again. Many thanks for the critical response and learning

Answer (score -1):

You need to maintain array of dictionaries , those dictionaries have keys like  "person", and "weight", then you can easily get weight value after selecting the cell by using  table view delegate method UITableViewDelegate's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance variable in your view controller (a var at the top level after the class definition) for the selected cell.

```
class MyTableViewController: UIViewController

var selectedRow: Int


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
  selectedRow = indexPath.row

  //invoke a segue if desired
  performSegueWithIdentifier("someSegue");
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
  sender: AnyObject?)
{
  if segue.identifier == "someSegue"
  {
    //Cast the destination view controller to the appropriate class
    let destVC = DestVCClass(segue.destinationViewController)
    destVC.selectedRow = selectedRow
  }
}
```

As Andey says in his answer, it's probably better to create a single array of data objects (dictionaries, structs, or custom data objects). Then when the user taps a cell, instead of passing the index of the selected row to the next view controller, you could pass the whole data object to the destination view controller. Then the destination view controller could extract whatever data it needed. (Weight, in your example.)

Comment: Why the down-vote? If you feel my answer is lacking, please post a comment explaining why.